# python django app settings log level

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django. My changes in app/settings.py are not picking up. I have changed the log level 
FROM:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
...
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},

'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
}
```

TO

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
...

 'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/django/debug.log'
     }
 },

 'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
     },
 }
}
```

but changes are not picking up as I don't see any activity on log despite actions on app. How could I tell Django that settings are updated and reload it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the web server for it to pick up changes in your app.

Comment: restart didn't help.